# Is there a special character to output a "new table column / cell" from python?

Tags: python

I've built a simple python script that inputs data in one format, and then outputs the same data in a different format, and then automatically copies that to my clipboard. The idea is to then be able to paste that string into a table in a program used at my workplace.

The output I have at the moment is essentially `'string' + '\t' + 'string2' + '\t' + 'string3'` and so on.

When you paste the string into Excel, Excel accepts it fine and says, "OK, this should be 3 columns". All good. And if I copy the cells from Excel, and paste that into the other program, the program accepts it as 3 columns of input.

But, herein lies the rub; the other program won't take that data directly. It just takes my strings and pops it into one cell in the table, with a tabspace between them.

My thought is that Excel does something to the data on the clipboard that says "these are in separate cells". It's either a special character or something in rich text. Is there a way to have python output either that richtext or that special character? Or where I could find it?

Comment: It is the tab (`\t`). Excel knows tab separates columns, you other program does not.

Comment: @Błotosmętek That's my issue. But excel does output _something_ that this other program accepts, and I want to know if I can output that instead of using `\t`.

Comment: I doubt it's using a plain text string at all. The Windows clipboard supports a lot more [clipboard formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) than that, and other platforms have their own surprisingly complex clipboard APIs. (Think of all the times you've copied and pasted images - you couldn't do that with a text-only clipboard.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks! I'm looking at what I can get out of Clipview now, and then I suppose I'll try and find a way to have python output it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone stumbles upon this; I managed to solve my issue.

Using Clipview, I worked out that excel also outputs the table in HTML, which the program will accept.

I then used [win32clipboard](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32clipboard.html) to load the data from python to the clipboard in the HTML format.